# Adding an extra field to a serializer without it being in the model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to add the field 'distance' to the fields included in the results. This field is however, not in the model or the serializer and I just wondered what the best way to return such a field would be? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The view is:

```
class PlaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows places to be viewed or edited.
    """

    current_lat = 54.52984
    current_lon = -1.5609

    """
    Haversine formula used to sort places by distance (closest first).
    """
    query = "select distinct id, (((acos(sin((" + format(current_lat) + \
            "*pi()/180)) * sin((lat*pi()/180))+cos((" + format(current_lat) + \
            "*pi()/180)) * cos((lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((" + format(current_lon) + \
            " - lon)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS distance " \
            "from mobileapi_place " \
            "order by distance asc"

    queryset = Place.objects.raw(query)
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
```

Below is the serializer.

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('title', 'lat', 'lon', 'featured_image_url', 'created_at')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) ?

It should be something like this.

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    distance = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('title', 'lat', 'lon', 'distance', 'featured_image_url', 'created_at')

    def get_distance(self, obj):
        return obj.distance
```